# Is it possible to assign editor styles to API tokens?

Tags: zerobrane

If I define my own API and I want to highlight values, classes and methods of my API in editor. How I can do it? Is it possible to assign some of keyword styles to api tokens?

Here is my `instead.lua` in `api` folder of ZBS:

```
return {
  instead = {
    type = "lib",
    description = "Библиотека INSTEAD",
    childs = {
      tiny = {
        type = "value",
        description = "Флаг «минималистичного INSTEAD», без графики и множества других возможностей."
      }
    }
  },
}
```

And this is some code snippet:

```
if not instead.tiny then 
  require "autotheme"
end
```

So I want `instead` and `tiny` to be highlighted in my code.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to highlight specific values and api tokens, but depends on their format. Do you have an example of the code you're interested in highlighting?

Comment: I've added examples to original question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [keyword highlighting](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/blob/master/cfg/user-sample.lua#L144-L155), but while it works for "instead" and "tiny", it will also have to be set for "instead.tiny", which is not ideal (this looks like a limitation in the version of the Scintilla editor component used by the IDE); see [this ticket](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/683) for a related discussion and explanation. You may also check a proposed [highlight property](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/pull/78) plugin that does something similar (although for all properties).

Comment: I just thought that keywords could be obtained automatically from api definitions. But this method is also ok. Althogh it will take more effort to implement.